# Minimizing un-necessary re-renders in a large list React component tree

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a large list with [this accordion](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible) on React Native. The problem I face is the re-renders that happening in the renderItem function. When the input changes in the Product component whole component tree is re-rendered. Is there way to stop re-rendering the whole component tree for input changes on the product component with using React.memo or React.useMemo ?

```
const categories = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Category A' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Category B' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Category B' },
]

const products = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Product A', category: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Product B', category: 1 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Product C', category: 2 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Product D', category: 2 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Product E', category: 3 },
]

const handleChange = (product, quantity) => {
    console.log('handle change event fired');
};

const renderHeader = (category) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{category.name}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const renderContent = (category) => {
    const categoryProducts = products.filter(product => product.category_id === category.id);

    const renderItem = (product) => {
        return (
            <Product
                key={product.id}
                product={product}
                handleChange={handleChange}
            />
        );
    };

    return (
        <View>
            {
                categoryProducts.map(product => {
                    return (renderItem(product));
                })
            }
        </View>
    );
};

return (
    <ScrollView>
        <Accordion
            sections={categories}
            renderHeader={renderHeader}
            renderContent={renderContent}
        />
    </ScrollView>
);
```

The Product Compoenent

```
<View>
    <Input
        size="small"
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        onChangeText={(changedQuantity) => {
            handleChange( product, changedQuantity);
        }}
        value={quantity}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: Try wrapping product component with React.memo and use useCallback for the function onChangeText function.

Comment: use useCallback for handleChange in the parent component also.

Comment: wrapping product component with React.memo worked! thanks.
useCallback for handleChange didn't work because I have a dependancy that changes in the useCallback